# Meta-Analysis (paired t-test)

Tags: meta-analysis, effect-size

I would like to combine within-study designs and between study designs in a meta-analysis.
My research question is if movement interventions increase cognitive ability.
So far, I have analyzed studies that report mean, standard deviation and samples size of independent groups. I also found studies that use cross-over trials, that report results of paired t-tests (for example: t(29)= 2.25 p <.05). Can I calculate Hedge's g from this data?

Comment: Does this help? https://training.cochrane.org/handbook/current/chapter-23#section-23-2

Comment: Thanks a lot for your comment.!Unfortunately, I don't find a formula on how to calculate an effect size if only a t-value is given. Formulas are based on means and SD as well as correlations. Unfortunatel,y I found many studies where these parameters are not reported.

Comment: Apart from doing that from first principles does https://campbellcollaboration.org/escalc/html/EffectSizeCalculator-SMD6.php help?

Comment: Thanks, can this be used for paired t-test?